# Compare result set from 2 sql queries in Python

Tags: python, sql

I have 2 same SQL queries from  different environments and the result set is stored in 2 variables .

```
query ='select * from employee'
r1 =  cursor1.execute(query)
r2 = cursor2.execute(query)
```

How to compare r1 and r2 for differences in records of employee table  in Python language.

Comment: What are the differences which you want to check, or how do you want to compare these two result sets logically?

Comment: the data in the tables needs to be compared